# Automate UVMap and Baking on object list

Tags: python, uv

I'm trying to generate and bake a new UVMap for each sub objects ( 4 piece_*.).

[image]

So i made this python script :

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for obji in bpy.data.objects:
    obji.select_set(False)

for obj in objs:
     if obj.name.startswith("piece"):
        print("ForLoop objects " + obj.name)
        image_name = obj.name + '_BakedTexture'
        img = bpy.data.images.new(image_name,2048,2048)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]
        obj.select_set(True)
        #bpy.context.active_object = obj
        print("Debug Active Object " + bpy.context.active_object.name)
        bpy.context.object.update_from_editmode()
        for mat in obj.data.materials:
            mat.use_nodes = True #Here it is assumed that the materials have been created with nodes, otherwise it would not be possible to assign a node for the Bake, so this step is a bit useless
            nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
            texture_node =nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
            texture_node.name = 'Bake_node'
            texture_node.select = True
            nodes.active = texture_node
            texture_node.image = img #Assign the image to the node

        #           bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()
        bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers["UVMap.001"].name = "UVBake"
        #bpy.context.object.update_from_editmode()
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]
        #bpy.context.area.type = "VIEW_3D"
        obj.select_set(True)
        #bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()                
        
        bpy.ops.uv.unwrap()
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]
        bpy.ops.object.bake(type='DIFFUSE', save_mode='EXTERNAL')
        img.save_render(filepath=exportFolder + "\\" + obj.name + '_baked.png')
        for mat in obj.data.materials:
            for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
                if n.name == 'Bake_node':
                    mat.node_tree.nodes.remove(n)

        #bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        print("end process " + obj.name)
        obj.select_set(False)
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

What is strange first , is that it's working only if i select the first piece so I guess all my treatment to select the object is not working fine.

And after that, it generate actually the 4 same textures so it seems that the selection is still on the first piece

EDIT :

I add some logs and it's so strange :

```
Got GET: {'type': 'ping'}
Got POST: {'type': 'script', 'path': 'd:\\Users\\x.larrode\\Documents\\Blender\\laRedoute\\UVObj.py'}
ForLoop objects piece_100_2_1_1
Debug Active Object piece_300_3_2_1
Info: Baking map saved to internal image, save it externally or pack it
end process piece_100_2_1_1
ForLoop objects piece_200_1_1_1
Debug Active Object piece_300_3_2_1
Info: Baking map saved to internal image, save it externally or pack it
end process piece_200_1_1_1
ForLoop objects piece_300_3_1_2
Debug Active Object piece_300_3_2_1
```

So as you can see the Active Object it's always the one i selected before lauching the python code...

Comment: So if i select Nothing, i come across a problem of context :
File UVObjAllInOne.py", line 63, in <module>
    bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()
 
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Any ideas?